# Ngx-swiper-wrapper disabled

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

I have loaded some data into my ngx-swiper-wrapper. However, when this happens, this swiper-button-disabled is loaded on to the next-button and prev-button. I tried removing this with javascript, but the swiper object still wouldnt scroll. I do not know if there is a way to refresh/reload the swiper object after getting the data.

```
  ngOnInit() {
         this.spinner.show().then( async () => {
          this.data.currentProgress.subscribe(progress => this.progress = progress);
          await this.eventService.fetchEvents();
          }).then(async () => {
            this.data.totalShuffledEvents.subscribe(shuffle => this.totalEvents = shuffle);
            var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-button-next');
            buttons[0].classList.remove("swiper-button-disabled");
          }).then(() => {
            this.spinner.hide();
          });
     }
```

```
          <swiper *ngIf="type == 'component' && show" class="swiper-container" fxFlex="auto" [config]="config" [disabled]="disabled" (indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)" (swiperTransitionStart)="onSwiperEvent('transitionStart')" (swiperTransitionEnd)="onSwiperEvent('transitionEnd')">
            <div *ngFor="let event of totalEvents" class="swiper-slide">
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution will be to use a container(parent) in retrieving totalEvents then pass it to your ngx-swiper-component via @Input.

Below is an example:
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush //very important

@ViewChild(SwiperDirective) swiperDirectiveRef: SwiperDirective;

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.swiperDirectiveRef) {
      this.swiperDirectiveRef.setIndex(0);
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      if (this.swiperDirectiveRef.swiper()) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.swiperDirectiveRef.swiper().lazy.load();
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
```

ALTERNATIVELY:
You can create a method for this and call it in your subscribe:

```
ngOnInit() {
         this.spinner.show().then( async () => {
          this.data.currentProgress.subscribe(progress => this.progress = progress);
          await this.eventService.fetchEvents();
          }).then(async () => {
            this.data.totalShuffledEvents.subscribe(shuffle => {
            this.totalEvents = shuffle;
            this.refreshSwipper();
           });
          }).then(() => {
            this.spinner.hide();
          });
     }

refreshSwipper() {
if (this.swiperDirectiveRef) {
          this.swiperDirectiveRef.setIndex(0);
          this.cdRef.detectChanges();
          if (this.swiperDirectiveRef.swiper()) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.swiperDirectiveRef.swiper().lazy.load();
            }, 0);
          }
        }
}
```